# Hash function of string

Tags: java, string, hash, binary

I am looking for a hash algorithm that have an input is a string and the output is the binary string.

For example :

```
hash("abc",8) = 11001010   //8 is the output bits number
```

I cannot find out any hash function like that.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "binary string"?

Comment: How do you get `11001010` for "abc"?

Comment: What language are you using ? C ? C++ ? Java ? ... Or is it a language agnostic question ?

Answer (score 0):

c#

```
string str = "Hello"; 
byte []arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: I am using Java to implement my code . Anyway, Thanks for your comment